# Change the Range Into First and Last column with Values

Tags: vba, excel

A little help for my working file is appreciated..

Below is my code, 
What I want is to set this formula to fixed Range.. `Sheets("Unire").Range("CB4:HJ4"))`
What I mean is The Range will start from (Row 4:Col CB) to Last Column in Row 4 with Values.

```
Sub Unire()
    Dim cell As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Unire").Activate
    For Each cell In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Sheets("Unire").Range("CB4:HJ4"))
        cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = cell.value <> Sheets("Command").Range("B5") And Not IsEmpty(cell)
    Next cell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: So, row 4 last filled column is HJ?

Comment: assuming it is the last col in a row with values as of now... but from time to time we're adding new column every month for the next month report. Hope this will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should your row 4 not empty cells be filled with "constant" (i.e. not deriving from formulas) values, then you could enhance your code speed by iterating only through not blank cells by means of `SpecialCells()` method of Range object

furthermore you'd better store `Sheets("Command").Range("B5").Value` in a helper variable once and for all instead of accessing it at *every* iteration

```
Option Explicit

Sub Unire()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim refVal As Variant

    refVal = Sheets("Command").Range("B5").Value '<--| store reference value for subsequent comparisons
    On Error GoTo ExitSub '<--| make sure to properly exit this sub should sunsequent statements (namely 'SpecialCells' one) raise any error
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Sheets("Unire")
        For Each cell In .Range("CB4", .cells(4, .columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)  ' <--| reference not empty cells from CB4 to last not-empty cell in row 4
            cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = cell.Value <> refVal
        Next
    End With

ExitSub:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
Sub Unire()
    Dim cell As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Sheets("Unire")
        For Each cell In .Range("CB4", .Range("XFD4").End(xlToLeft)) ' <-- from CB4 to last non-empty on row 4
            cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = cell.value <> Sheets("Command").Range("B5").value And Not IsEmpty(cell)
        Next cell
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```